# Why am I getting the same object pushed into my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to build an array of places from Yelp's response. However, after pushing and passing my array into the callback to be returned I end up with the same 4 places instead of 4 unique places.

```
    let rawResult = arrayBusinesses.jsonBody.businesses;
    let arrVenues = new Array();
    // console.log(rawResult);
    let venue = {
        type: 'venue',
        id: '',
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        title: '',
        address: ''
       // thumb_url: ''
    };


    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log('i', i);
        (function(j){
            console.log('j' + j);
            let bus = rawResult[j];
            venue.type = 'venue';
            venue.id = j+'a';
            venue.latitude = bus.coordinates.latitude;
            venue.longitude = bus.coordinates.longitude;
            venue.title = bus.name;
            venue.address = bus.location.address1;
            arrVenues.push(venue);
        })(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is hard to read how about something like

```
const arrVenues = rawData.slice(0, 5)
.map((place, index) => (
  {
    type: 'venue',
    id: `${index}a`,
    latitude: place.coordinates.latitude,
    longitude: place.coordinates.longitude,
    title: place.name',
    address: place.location.address,
 }
));
```

How ever to answer your question the problem is that you keep pushing the same object every time. when you do `arrVenues.push(venue)` is always the same object, literally the same memory location. since you never take time to make a copy of the object and just modify is properties you end up with an array of the same object.

Comment: Hmm, thanks you were spot on and I appreciate you cleaning up the code. I'm still confused, for some reason I don't understand what you mean by 'make a copy'

Comment: objects are memory locations, when you pushed it into the array all you did was push a pointer to that memory location so any alterations done after that will affect the elements in the array. in order to prevent that you need to make a copy of the object using either deconstruction `push({...venue})` or `push(Object.assign({}, venue)` or any other copy method depending on your tools belt.

Comment: Oh, I see now why I got 5 copies of the last object in the array. Thanks!